# How to send data in a jsp form (Registration) to another jsp page (Admin panel) without inserting to database

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Is there any method to show data in a jsp form in another jsp page, like,

Show the data of Registration form in Admin panel, without sending data to a database. But after registering the page is not redirecting to the admin panel.

index.jsp

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name">
        <select class="custom-select-md" id="uni_select">
             <option selected>Select your university</option>
                  <%
                    try {
                         Connection conn = DBConnect.connect();
                         String sql = "SELECT * FROM universities";
                         Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                         ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                         while (rs.next()) {
                  %>
             <option value="<%=rs.getString("id")%>"><%=rs.getString("uni_name")%></option>
                  <%
                         }
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                             System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
                       }
                  %>
       </select>
       <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="University ID number" name="index" id="index">
       <input class="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="mail" id="mail">
       <input type="submit" class="btnR btn btn-dark btn-block" name="s_reg" value="Register as a Student" id="regStu"/>
</form>
```

I want to show Name, University name, ID no and the email on admin panel without sending this data to the database. After the approving the data by the admin, he inputs this data to the database.

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps

### First Jsp Page

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ page session="false"%>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="main.jsp" method="GET">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"> <br /> Last
            Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" /> <input type="submit"
                value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### Second JSP page (page name main.jsp)

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Using GET Method to Read Form Data</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Using GET Method to Read Form Data</h1>
      <ul>
         <li><p><b>First Name:</b>
            <%= request.getParameter("first_name")%>
         </p></li>
         <li><p><b>Last  Name:</b>
            <%= request.getParameter("last_name")%>
         </p></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```